# Using the data from ajax success() event with other event handlers in the same .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a "submit" button and attached to it is a event handler that uses Jquery/ajax. The data for the success function is coming from a flask view:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  var final_data;    //tried defining here
  var input_ID = $("#input_ID").val();
  var Node_Type = $("#Node_Type").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    dataType: 'json',

    data: {
      input_ID: input_ID,
      Node_Type: Node_Type,

    },
    success: function(data) {
      var IDData = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(IDData);
      var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);

      var startnodes = [];
      var endnodes = [];
      var startnodetype = [];
      var endnodetype = [];
      var SendTime = [];
      var PayTime = [];
      var Total_Amt = [];
      var Depth = [];
      galData.map(function(e, i) {
        startnodes.push(e[0]);
        endnodes.push(e[1]);
        startnodetype.push(e[2]);
        endnodetype.push(e[3]);
        SendTime.push(e[4]);
        PayTime.push(e[5]);
        Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
        Depth.push(e[7]);
      });
      var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth);
      makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);

    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Both the

```
createNodes() and makeGraph()
```

Functions work fine and the code for both of them is in the same .js file as the event handler.

I want to use

```
var final_data
```

In other event handlers in the same .js file.

```
      var filtered_data = [];
var myBtn = document.getElementById("depth");

if (myBtn) {
  myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var nodes = [];
    var links = [];

    var e = document.getElementById("select_ID");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(strUser);
    d3.selectAll("line").filter(function(d, i) {
      if (d.depth <= strUser) {
        if (isUnique(d.source.id, nodes)) {
          nodes.push(d.source);
        }

        if (isUnique(d.target.id, nodes)) {
          nodes.push(d.target);
        }
        links.push(d);
      }
    });
    filtered_data.links = links;
    filtered_data.nodes = nodes;
    filtered_data.nodetype = final_data.nodetype;
    d3.select('#Network_graph').selectAll("*").remove();
    makeGraph("#Network_graph", filtered_data);
  });
}
var fullBtn = document.getElementById("full_data");

if (fullBtn) {
  fullBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    d3.select('#Network_graph').selectAll("*").remove();
    makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);
  });
}
```

Failed with:

```
     Uncaught ReferenceError: final_data is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Comment: You could declare var final_data outside of the function so it stays in scope.  Like a global variable.

Comment: var IDdata = Json.stringify(data)..now that "data" comes from the backend flask view and only gets picked up in the success(data). It does not stay valid outside that success(data). And var final_data is dependent on the IDData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, objects and functions are also variables. That's why you are able to access `createNodes()` and `makeGraph()` outside your callback. [Scope](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) is the set of variables, objects, and functions you have access to. The scope changes once inside a function. like your callback, they then become local and cannot be accessed outside **that** scope, only within that function. This is why you cannot access `final_data` anywhere else. Assign that varabiable before `jQuery.ajax()` and you'll have access to it globally.

Comment: problem is var final_data if you observed is dependent on var IDData = Json.stringify(data) . And Json.stringify(data) only seems to work inside the success() event handler.

Comment: @optimus_prime Just set it outside the scope. `var final_data;` and set the value within your callback.

Comment: Tried defining var final_data; outside the scope as suggested but no luck.

Comment: @optimus_prime Updated your question with your revised code.

Comment: Question is updated now. Also added exact code for the event listeners.

Comment: Do not reinitialize `final_data` within your callback. Use `final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth);` instead of `var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth);`. Interesting enough, are you still receiving the `final_data is not defined` error? Try binding it to the window object, if nothing else. (i.e. `window.final_data`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130736/discussion-between-optimus-prime-and-daerik).

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable at the Outermost function Scope or outside of the Event handler callback. Basically, you need to ensure that variable  `final_data` is accessible to other methods. This can be achieved by placing the variable outside of the function.

But keep in mind that declaring variables in outermost scope can lead to creating global variable, which can lead to object collision. So you can try to wrap all the code inside a IIFE.

```
(function(){
var final_data; 
... All you code

// Function definition1

// Function definition1

// Function definition1

})();
```

Comment: so I defined final_data outside as suggested . But even then getting a uncaught reference error. Updated the post.